# Typesetting bilinear operators in second quantisation

Tags: physics, tensor

When typesetting certain operators in quantum many-body theory, I often find that they look aesthetically a bit questionable. Having a dagger on a symbol seems to shove the index down. The most straightforward fix I have found for this has been to use the ``tensor"-package as shown below. However, the indices here does not look exactly aligned either. I would really appreciate a simpler solution.

Example:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \text{(a)} \quad a^{\dagger}_{i} a_i \qquad \text{(b)} \quad a^{\dagger}_{i} \tensor{a}{_i}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: You do not mention what engine you are using. If you use luatex, you can change the behaviour when there is both a sub- and a superscript, by setting the `\mathscriptsmode` (see section 7.5.7 in the [luatex manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/systems/doc/luatex/luatex.pdf). You can see different versions with the relevant levels shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxSHA.png). (Top: default complex algorithm, middle: pretend there is not sub- and superscripts bottom: always assume there is sub- and superscript.)

Answer (score 3):

The macro `\mathstrut` -- defined as `\vphantom{(}` -- is your friend. Use it to create an "empty" superscript term for the second instance of `a_i`. Alternatively, you could write `a^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_i` to force the subscript term (`i`) to be placed at the desired depth.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tensor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
a^{\dagger}_{i} a_i \quad 
a^{\dagger}_{i} \tensor{a}{_i} \quad
a^{\dagger}_{i} a^{\mathstrut}_i \quad
a^{\dagger}_{i} a^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_{i}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you use Unicode math Latin Modern font, then the problem isn't observable. The vertical position of indices are almost equal. I tried Unicode math with OpTeX (but this is font feature, irrelevant what macro is used):

```
\fontfam[lm]
$$
a^\dagger_i a_i \quad 
a^\dagger_i a^{\mathstrut}_i \quad
$$
\bye
```

[image: ai]

Answer (score 2):

Aligning subscripts when some letters are also superscripted always requires some manual intervention. In most cases adding an empty superscript `^{}` is sufficient.

For the case of `\dagger`, which is quite big in vertical extension, this isn't really the solution (there is a small difference in height of the subscripts.

You might reduce the size of `\dagger` and make TeX think it has no depth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewCommandCopy{\daggersymbol}{\dagger}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dagger}{{\mathpalette\dagger@\relax}}
\newcommand{\dagger@}[2]{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{0.9}{$\m@th#1\daggersymbol$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a_i^{\daggersymbol}a_i^{}$ (original)

$a_i^{\dagger}a_i^{}$ (scaled)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\mathstrut` (as shown in the answer by @wipet) should also work in LaTeX.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes but it pushes further down  the subscript